# Android WebView crash using local web page

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, crash

Can a webview in an android application crash due to errors in client side webpage. I tried loading a local webpage into the webview and crash that by throwing javascript errors and brute force attacks but the webview/app dint crash. I am working on a project which does analysis of the crashes(number of crashes etc.) by an apk.

JUST TELLING HOW TO CRASH A WEB-VIEW IN ANDROID APP WOULD BE REALLY HELPFUL, IRRESPECTIVE OF THE JAVA CODE BELOW.(Crashing should not done by throwing exception on some webview event. Basically, not from java.)

Following is the code I added in local webpage :

```
function myCrashFun() {

    for(var i=0; i===i; i++) { Console.log("Hello123"); } //brute force attack

    var num=1;
    num.toUpperCase(); //typeError

}
</script><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myCrashFun()">Click to crash!</button>
```

following is the code for webview activity using hello.html local webage :

```
public class WebviewTest extends Activity
{
    WebView wv;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_test);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);

        //If the web page you plan to load in your WebView use JavaScript, you must enable JavaScript for your WebView.
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        //WebSettings provides access to a variety of other settings that you might find useful.

        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
}
```

I don't want a webview to crash by throwing java exception/error. That part is already handled. Is there any way to crash the web view, using javascript or some client side technology..

Comment: post stack trace

Comment: share your logcat.

Comment: `Can a webview .. crash` - yes, it can. But nobody knows for sure how.